# "Internet" Android browser HTML Div Page Issue

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, html, css

We've been facing an issue for several days trying to figure out how to make our website works perfectly on android browsers, the problem is that the text comes overlapped on android devices, how ever there's a good solution for the newer android versions that does have the Google Chrome browser installed by default, we added a code into the header that fixes that text issue, here it is

I'm surprised that the issue is still happening on the Android internet browser, here is a screenshot of how it is working on Internet browser ( URL: http://compassgames.net/test/ )

[image]

All other browser is fine, Desktop, iOS, Android Google Chrome Browser

I would love to know the solution as many of my users/clients does actually have that Internet browser installed.

Waiting for your replies

Thank you

Cheers,

Ahmed

Comment: The paragraphs look overlapped in my desktop Chrome browser too. So, it's not really an Android browser issue.

Comment: Are you sure? I'm testing it at the time of this writing and it is working fine?